# Sampling stationary distribution of SDE by solving numerical scheme

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

currently I am learning the stochastic differential equation and their numerical approximations and something is bothering me. Some processes has stationary distributions if stationary Fokker-Planck equation is solved. However, we need the Fokker-Planck equation for this. We can also simulate different realizations by solving numerically the SDE:

$dX =a(X)*dt+b(X)*dB$

My question: is it possible somehow to sample the stationary distribution if I solve the following equation:

$0 =a(X_{eq})*dt+b(X_{eq})*dB$

The reason why I am asking is that in deterministic case one solves always the

$ A*x_{eq} = f $

linear equation (or system) to calculate the stationary solution $x_{eq}$. This is obviously impossible in stochastic case because the $f$ source term is random. But if we do this step enough then we should see the $X_{eq}$ when the $dX=0$ (it is stationary), should we not?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: If you impose that the diffusion is recurrent one knows that $\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}f(X_{t})dt=\int f d\gamma$ with $\gamma$ being the invariant measure. That gives a good starting point for numerically sampling from $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a solution $X_{\mathrm{eq}}$ that satisfies your equation
$$
0\, =\, a(X_{\mathrm{eq}}) dt + b(X_{\mathrm{eq}}) dB_t
$$
and which also satisfies $dX_{\mathrm{eq}} = a(X_{\mathrm{eq}}) dt + b(X_{\mathrm{eq}}) dB_t$ then that would mean that $X_{\mathrm{eq}}$ is not only stationary: it is non-random and constant in $t$. That is fine. There are such solutions to some SDE's. For example $dX = X\, dt + X\, dB_t$. Then one solution is $X=0$. But a more general family of solutions is $X=A \exp(B_t+\frac{1}{2}t)$ with $A=0$ giving the only solution which is stationary. (But it is also constant, and $0$.)

Comment: Dear Shannon Starr! You are absolutly right, I did not think about that. However i am also interested in that case when X is not 0. I mean if there is something mean-reversing process and it has a stationary distribution then solving $dX = a(X_{eq})dt+b(X_{eq})dB_t$ will change in time but it remains being stationary distributed. So the edited question: is it possible to find a $X_{eq}$ by solving the stationary equation and has the property mentioned above?